# JQuery .post() not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass parameters to the [TinyPaste](http://www.tinypaste.com/) API. I have the following JQuery script in an HTML file,

```
$.post("http://tinypaste.com/api/create.json", 
    { 
     "paste": "This is test paste", 
     "title": "Test",
     "is_code": 0,
     "is_private": 1
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

As seen in the Firefox's Web Console, I can see that the request is made and is successful (The content length of the response is as expected). But the callback function is not printing anything in the console window.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please tell us, where you are working on. Some extension? Or a normal web page? Because there's a cross domain request. Or if resorting to GET, you might just exceed the maximum length..

Comment: No I am working on a normal webpage.

Comment: In that case, POST(`$.post`) will not work. As for doing GET-ish methods (that is if at all there's some hack, since JSONP is also not supported), you will soon run out of maximum length when you submit long codes.

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this

```
  $.post("http://tinypaste.com/api/create.json", 
            { 
             'paste': "This is test paste", 
             'title': "Test",
             'is_code': 0,
             'is_private': 1
            },
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            'jsonp'
        );
```

You must send also a data type to server, means `jsonp`.

Comment: But in this example http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-4 they are not using success. Why is it so?

Comment: what difference does it make if param keys are quoted or not?

Comment: It does not matter, this is valid json: { 
     "paste": "This is test paste", 
     "title": "Test",
     "is_code": 0,
     "is_private": 1
    }

Comment: I have edited my answer, no matter, you have rights. I added `jsonp` as data type to make `$.post` working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are making a request to another domain from your website and this violates the SAME ORIGIN POLICY of browers, you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to work around this..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: POST does not work for cross domain USE $.getJSON instead**

```
$.getJSON("http://tinypaste.com/api/create.json", 
    { 
     "paste": "This is test paste", 
     "title": "Test",
     "is_code": 0,
     "is_private": 1
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

It is entirely possible the API does not serve JSONP, in which case you will need to resort to alternate methods

Comment: says he's getting data back, have to assume it is jsonp for now

Comment: something's all wrong since have to use Get cross domain anyway

Comment: The problem actually lies somewhere else. The configuration of allowed domains (or something) -- thats what I doubt. That is, in case he is working on an extension. Otherwise, it doesn't sound possible to me.

Comment: @Thrustmaster you are right. I think Tinypaste doesn't support JSONP!

Answer (score 0):

The major (and only) problem with the script posted in the question is that it is making a cross domain HTTP/POST request while on a normal webpage. I previously believed you were working on some browser extension, which if configured properly will allow you to have cross-domain requests. HTTP/POST will just not work in your case. Although there are hacks to get HTTP/GET working, like using the script tag, and JSONP.

In your case, what I suggest is let your server (which serves out your page) carry out the request for you.

The process will be:

- You submit a request to the server with the parameters for tinypaste.
- The server side script will do the HTTP/POST to tinypaste, and fetch the response. This response is sent across to the browser.
- Browser gets the response. (and may be redirects or something)

Or as @charlietfl suggests, you could use [YQL and Jquery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/)

Comment: YQL and JQuery will be sending a POST or a GET request?

Comment: It will be a GET request. Cross domain POST request is not possible.